# Pythonでテキスト処理する際のprintを見やすくしたい

Tags: python

Pythonでテキスト処理をしています。

変数textにテキスト情報が入っています。

textを実行すると、テキスト情報が見れると思うのですが、改行が`\n`として表示され、1行でまとめて出力されます。
これが見づらく、改善したいのですが、良い方法があればご教示いただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

8/25 追記

PyCharmでpython 3.7.9を使用しています。例えば、

```
text = "スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ\nスタック・オーバーフロー は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のた\nめのQ&Aサイトです。ユーザーによるユーザーのためのQ&Aコミュニティの集まりである、Stack Exchange ネットワ\nークの一部として運営されています。目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り\n上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。"
```

として、コンソールで

```
text
```

を実行すると、

```
'スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ\nスタック・オーバーフロー は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のた\nめのQ&Aサイトです。ユーザーによるユーザーのためのQ&Aコミュニティの集まりである、Stack Exchange ネットワ\nークの一部として運営されています。目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り\n上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。'
```

と出力されます。
これが1行で出力され見づらいため、

```
"スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ
スタック・オーバーフロー は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のた
めのQ&Aサイトです。ユーザーによるユーザーのためのQ&Aコミュニティの集まりである、Stack Exchange ネットワ
ークの一部として運営されています。目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り
上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。"
```

と改行された状態で出力させたいのですが、どのように行えますでしょうか。
初歩的な質問で大変恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: データの内容や表示結果と、動作環境や版数、使っているIDE等の情報の詳細を追記してみてください。ちなみに関係無いかもしれませんがこんな記事があります。[Pythonのprintで改行あり・改行なしの制御方法を徹底解説！](https://ai-inter1.com/python-print-break/), [【入門者向け】Pythonの改行について徹底解説](https://blog.codecamp.jp/python-strat-a-new-line), [Python printで改行なしの出力を解説](https://muusannitizyou.jp/python-print-no-new-line/), [Pythonで改行を扱う方法を解説！｜改行コード・改行削除など](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/50508)

Comment: あるいは単に改行コードを文字列に含める/指定するのに`\n`ではなくバックスラッシュが1つ多い`\\n`が使われているだけかもしれませんね。

Comment: `print(text)` とするのが簡単でしょうね。もしくは `text.split('\n')`

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに改行されて出力されました。
textと打てば、内部的にはprint(text) が実行されているのだろうと思い込んでいたのですが、別のことが実行されていると考えてよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: @TR123 Jupyter とかだったら, `display()` 相当が呼び出されます。`display(text)` で同じ結果が出るならたぶんそう。

Comment: display(text)で同様の出力でした。勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(解決したようなのでコメントから転記)
(追記により PyCharm 環境と判明)

このような(Jupyter的な？) 環境の場合, セルの最後に入力した項目は `display()` を呼び出したような表示が行われます。
(`Out[数字]` なども表示されてるはずで, 別セルなどから `Out[数字]`でアクセス可能なように管理も行われます)

(たぶん PyCharm もそう)

`'\n'` を改行文字として扱うには次のようにします

```py
print(text)
# もしくは
text.split('\n')
```

---

(Pandas DataFrame など表示する分には, display() の方が都合がいいはず)

Answer (score 0):

あなたが何を期待しているのかは明確ではありません。 `\n`を削除したい場合は、

```
text = '\n'.join([x for x in text.split('\n') if len(x) != 1])
```